# How do I write the AJAX to post data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmvpesxm/)

I am trying to learn AJAX from a tutorial.

I am able to grab the data I want and populate it in the DOM pretty easily.

What I'm struggling with is using 'POST' to edit it.

I created a simple page that lists 'friends' and 'ages' that pulls that data from here

http://rest.learncode.academy/api/learncode/friends

The names and ages populate correctly, but the code I'm writing to 'POST' to it is not.

Here is my javascript

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var $friends = $('#friends');
        var $name = $('#name');
        var $age = $('#age');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/learncode/friends',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("I have friends!", data); 
                $.each(data, function(i, name){
                    $friends.append('<li>name: '+ name.name + '<br />' + ' age:' + name.age +' </li>');
                })
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error loading data");
            }
        });
        $('#add-order').on('click', function () {

        });
    });
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div class="large-12 columns" id="ajaxContainer">
    <h1>
        AJAX Container
    </h1>
    <h3>
        Friends
    </h3>
    <ul id="friends">

    </ul>
    <h3>Add a friend</h3>

    <p>
        Name:
        <input type="text" id="name" />
    </p>
    <p>
        Age:
        <input type="text" id="age" />
    </p>
    <button id="add-order"> submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: A: You're not POSTing, you're GETting. B: You're probably violating same origin rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing as to what you actually want, but it seems that you want the page to populate with whatever friends are currently in the database on first load, and then when you click add-order button, it adds new friends and updates your list. The first thing is that you are trying to POST to the learncode name, which you can't do. Change where it says "yourname" in the URLs below to something else. Here is what you should do:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        var $friends = $('#friends');
        var $name = $('#name');
        var $age = $('#age');

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/yourname/friends',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log("I have friends!", data); 
                $.each(data, function(i, name){
                    $friends.append('<li>name: '+ name.name + '<br />' + ' age:' + name.age +' </li>');
                })
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error loading data");
            }
        });
        $('#add-order').on('click', function () {


          $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               data: {"id":3, "age": $age.val(), "name":$name.val()},
               url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/yourname/friends',
               success: function () {
                $.ajax({
                   type: 'GET',
                   url: 'http://rest.learncode.academy/api/yourname/friends',
                   success: function (data) {
                     $friends.html("");
                     console.log("I have friends!", data); 
                     $.each(data, function(i, name){
                       $friends.append('<li>name: '+ name.name + '<br />' + ' age:' + name.age +' 
</li>');
                })
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error loading data");
            }
        });
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("error loading data");
            }
        });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

See the part that says

`type : "GET"`

-?-
change it to

`type : "POST"`

Then, the url parameter is what you are `POST`ing to-

And you are not actually sending any data -!

So, try this:

```
$(function () {
    var $friends = $('#friends');
    var $name = $('#name');
    var $age = $('#age');

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://yourWebsite.com/someScriptToHandleThePost.php',
        data: [{"id":1,"name":"Will","age":33},{"id":2,"name":"Laura","age":27}],
        success: function (data) {
            console.log("I have friends!", data); 
            $.each(data, function(i, name){
                $friends.append('<li>name: '+ name.name + '<br />' + ' age:' + name.age +' </li>');
            })
        },
        error: function () {
            alert("error loading data");
        }
    });
    $('#add-order').on('click', function () {

    });
});
```

Then, you're going to need a PHP script to handle the POSTed data and return a response, which gets passed in the `data` param in  `success:function(data){}`

start out with something simple, like this:

```
<?php 


print_r($_POST); 


?>
```

and change your success function to:

```
success: function(data) {

     $("body").append("<pre>"+data+"</pre>");

}
```

and that should get you on the right track....